# Dart RegEx for JCB credit card failed

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, credit-card

I use following RegEx to identify JCB credit card.

I found the RegEx from here
https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html

```
input.startsWith(new RegExp(r'(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}'))
```

When I validate the following card number, it does not identify it correctly

```
3088000000000009
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: But your pattern clearly does not match the string. See some links to answers with matching regexps.

Comment: Yes definitely won't match.  The 3088 doesn't match at the second 8.

Comment: I've found that almost every regex from that site that is longer than a dozen chars is broken.  The one matching email is laughingly wrong, except that I see it being cargo-culted into many applications, ande it makes me sad.